# Is there a way to dump messages from an ActiveMQ queue and then reimport them?

Tags: activemq-classic

I am running ActiveMQ inside a container. I have an application that sends few hundred messages to an ActiveMQ queue. I would like to take a dump of those messages and stop the container. Next time i start an activemq container, i would like to use the dump i saved earlier and import those messages into the queue. Is this possible? ActiveMQ CLI commands are preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I developed my own ActiveMQ command line utility (activemq-cli) to do this. You can find it here: https://github.com/antonwierenga/activemq-cli (command 'export-messages' (to dump the messages to a file and 'send-message' to import them again).

[image]